# Operator - Exponential form

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, exponential-function, operator-algebras

It is well known that for every unitary operator $\hat U$ an exponential of the form 
$$
\hat U = e^{i\hat H}
$$

exists ($\hat H$ is hermitian). But I can only prove it the other way round:

$$
(e^{i\hat A})^\dagger = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n(A^n)^\dagger}{n!}=e^{-i\hat A^\dagger}=e^{-i\hat A}
$$
with $A$ hermitian.

Now suppose
$$
\hat U\hat U^\dagger = e^{i\hat A} e^{-i\hat A}=1
$$

so $\hat U$ has to be unitary. So now I have proven the statement that for every hermitian operator there exists a unitary operator, right?

Now how do I know that I can always find an exponential form of a unitary operator? Is this statement eventually true "in both directions"?

Comment: In general, if $U$ is a unitary from a unital C*-algebra $A$, it will be the product of many exponentials of that form iff it belongs to the connected component of the unit of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

A unitary operator is a diagonalizable operator whose eigenvalues all have unit norm. If we switch into the eigenvector basis of U, we get a matrix like:
\begin{bmatrix}e^{ia}&0&0\\0&e^{ib}&0\\0&0&e^{ic}\\\end{bmatrix}
which is obviously the exponential of a diagonal hermitian matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spectral theorem for normal operators. $H = -i \log(U)$ (for any branch of the logarithm).

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide any material on the spectral theorem for normal operators?

Comment: E.g. Rudin, "Functional Analysis".  Or you might try https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/ln-spec-thm.pdf